# Filter out and kill non-docker processes

Tags: process, kill, docker, ps

I have some processes that I am running both locally and within docker containers on the same host. Since I run multiple processes with the same name, I would like to make an alias/function that would allow me to kill all of them that are running on the host, but ignore the ones that are running in docker.

The command that I am using now has this form:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'process_name' | awk '{print $2}')
```

I noticed that this command kills the processes with the same name in all of the running containers which makes them crash. How can I prevent this?

This is how the process on the host machine looks like (as a result of ps aux):

```
hamzam   9109  0.9  0.0 510912 24732 ?        Ssl  14:21   0:00 python /opt/scripts/ex_script __name:=process_name __log:=/home/hamzam/.logs/0286c734-71fd-11e7-9dc4-901b0ed728a7/process_name-3.log
```

And this is the process which is run in one of the containers:

```
hamzam  12168  2.3  0.0 472708 64312 ?        Ssl  14:22   0:00 python /opt/scripts/ex_script __name:=process_name __log:=/home/logs/0/126e36dc-71fd-11e7-bd98-0242ac110003/process_name-3.log
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an example of the relevant lines from the output of `ps aux`. Show at least one you would want to kill and one you would want to keep. Also, as a general rule, you don't use `ps | grep` for this sort of thing. That's what `pkill` is for.

Comment: @terdon Thanks! I have added the examples now.

Comment: As you can see, they look identical so this won't be possible with `ps aux`. You will need to use the parent PID, probably. Could you show us the output of `pstree $pid` where `$pid` is the PID of each of the two (host and container) python processes?

Comment: They are the same `\python───5*[{python}]`. Also, I don't get the same results when I do `ps aux` and `pkill`. When I do `pkill 'process_name'` nothing happens actually, only when I do `pkill python`, but I don't want to kill all the python processes. EDIT: `pkill -f` works. Sorry for so many edits!

Comment: `pkill` has `--ns pid` and `--nslist name...`  options which you can use to limit the slaughter to a specific namespace.   e.g. using pkill with `--ns $$` from sh/bash/etc should kill only matching processes in the same namespace as your shell (all your docker containers will be in different namespaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkill` has `--ns pid` and `--nslist name...` options which can be used to restrict which namespaces the kill will affect.

The `--ns pid` combines well with the bash built-in variable `$$`, which is equal to the current shell's PID.

For example, on one of my systems, I run an instance of gitlab in docker, and one of the services it runs in that container is redis:

```
# ps u -C redis-server
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
997      30006  0.1  0.0  35504  2896 ?        Ssl  16:05   0:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:0
```

Note the PID, 30006.

If I use pkill's `-ns $$` option, then it won't be kill because it's in a different namespace to my shell.  Note how the PID has not changed - this indicates that it has not been killed and restarted.

```
# pkill --ns $$ redis-server
# ps u -C redis-server
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
997      30006  0.1  0.0  35504  2896 ?        Ssl  16:05   0:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:0
```

If i **don't** use that option, then (unsurprisingly) it will be killed.

```
# pkill redis-server
# ps u -C redis-server
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
997        459  0.5  0.0  35504  2896 ?        Ssl  16:11   0:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:0
```

The PID of redis-server is now 459.  It has been killed and restarted.

BTW, `pgrep` supports the same options, so it's easy to get a list of other processes in the same namespaces.  e.g. `pgrep -a --ns 459` shows me all processes running in the same namespace as the redis-server above.

---

`ps` also has various output format options for displaying namespace details. For example:

```
# ps -o pidns,pid,cmd -C redis-server
     PIDNS   PID CMD
4026532661   459 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:0
```

From `man ps`:

> pidns       PIDNS
>
> Unique inode number describing the namespace the process belongs to. See namespaces(7).

Comment: Thank you. This gave me more than enough information to make it work. For some reason, most likely since I am running the command from a script using popen, pkill does not do anything. So instead, I simply used kill -9 $(pgrep ...) with pgrep args that filters the namespace of $$.